# How should I pick an accent color?

Tags: color, interface-design, palette

I'm trying to find a good accent color to #411E50 (dark purple). #FD9827 (orange) has been suggested to me, but I'm leaning towards something like #F0C85D. However, the people I've asked didn't really like it. How can I find a good accent color without resorting to "personal taste"?

Comment: Start with Paletton.com and input your purple base, choose a different colour set and it will show you complementary colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not compare the company colours to a halloween store as that might sound like your opinion rather than proof when confronting your CEO.

Rather suggest that the orange is too dominating and taking a subtler route will make the information processing easier.

Always think what the change could do for the company rather than your own interpretations of what is happening. That'll help you further anchor your suggestion to the CEO. Something along the lines of "The visual hierarchy of the primary and secondary colours are conflicting. By changing the secondary pumpkin orange to *colour* it allows us to better visualise data by not distracting and overburdening the clients."

I would suggest looking at [Kuler](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/?base=2&rule=Analogous&selected=2&name=My%20Color%20Theme&mode=rgb&rgbvalues=1,0.8482366977233808,0.2519607843137255,0.91,0.7032748620379956,0.22928431372549019,1,0.7176470588235294,0.30196078431372547,0.91,0.5390843113080556,0.22928431372549019,1,0.4833112898092393,0.2519607843137255&swatchOrder=0,1,2,3,4) as well as browse a few [material design colour libraries](https://material.google.com/style/color.html) to see what other people use that base colour with. Google also provides an extensive guide to the use of colour with material design principles.

Do some research on the use of colour to further bolster your argument with facts and I'm sure your CEO will accept the change.

Source: Same personal experience with Blue and Green.

Answer (score 0):

Perosnally, the first color combination is not that bad. An interesting base combination.

I am not sure what is the base color, I supose the purple one. Simply have a pallete, not only a secondary fixed color, but a cuple of colors to play, let us think at least 3. The pumkin orange, a lighter one and a darker one for example.

Now you have an excuse to use another orange. A "pumkin interior" orange.

Answer (score 0):

When choosing a site's main/accent colour, I usually base it on the company's logo, and the other colours I use are usually determined by a colour rule, sometimes with variations.

I can agree that the yellow looks a lot better than the orange, perhaps if the orange was a little softer, it might work better.

I use [Kuler](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/) a lot and it's quite handy to find out which ones match the base colour.